# MPMoviePlayerViewController is playing video in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

i have a UIWebView that loads URLs from Address Bar, problem is that when i visit video website in this and open a video it loads that video in fullscreen, Now at the moment video is playing as topmost ViewController, i get some NSNotification *"that i have added over AppDelegate"* to dismiss currently playing video and do some other stuff.. i dismiss the MPMoviePlayerViewController

```
[navController dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
```

it just hide **MPMoviePlayerViewController** View while the video is still playing in background, My question is that how can i dismiss **MPMoviePlayerViewController** permanantly so that everything get stop..

Comment: try to stop before dismissal

Comment: how can i stop that player as i have not created that MPMoviePlayerViewController, this player is automatically created by UIWebView by just clicking a video insidethat webview... i hav'nt got that player refernce

Comment: When using a `UIWebView` to play a video, there is no `MPMoviePlayerViewController` involved. The playback is done by an internal implementation that just has an interface looking like the one from `MPMoviePlayerController`. To stop the video, you will have to invoke some javascript within your `UIWebView`.

Comment: ..alternatively, simply destroy the entire `UIWebView` which should take care of stopping the video.

Comment: Thanks @Till , i just solved the issue.. see Answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this issue by just first dismissing MoviePlayerViewController by

```
[nav.view.window.rootViewController dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
```

and after dismissing Player i just reload UIWebview by again requesting the url as

```
 [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```